# transparency with iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

im using iframe to desplay some pages that hold a gallerys and i added
2 divs that 1 of them is an arrow build by borders.

now when i try to see the 2 divs with the iframe the background on the div that holds the arrow is white i tryed to set the background color:

> background-color:transparent;

but it didnt work.

is there  any way to make the div background transparent?

i should add that the page that hold the iframe got an image.

this is the css of the arrow:

```
border-color: #ffffff #a0c7ff #ffffff #ffffff;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 37px;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
```

Comment: Can you show the CSS of the arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add to the iframe:

```
allowTransparency="true"
```

[**UPDATE**]

The problem might be your arrow itself. You need to make the borders you don't want to see transparent instead of white. Compare these two:

http://jsfiddle.net/XtMCa/

And this (your CSS), which has a white background:

http://jsfiddle.net/XtMCa/1/

Comment: i can still see the white color any other ideas?

Comment: I think we need more details on the div that you are trying to make transparent.

Comment: im not sure what info i can add please tell me and i will be happy to add it :)

Comment: I updated my answer because I had a different idea. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

```
.transparent_div
  {
  width:400px;
  height:180px;
  margin:30px 50px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }
```

Comment: i tryed to make a div with this css code and put my aroww div inside it but i can still see the white background in the iframe.